# How to fetch values and combine them using eloquent in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to display description of the values related to the id's in my list table.

Comment: Describe how your tables are related and how data is stored in database, looks wrong data structure to me.

Comment: @TheAlpha thanks for the response. I just want to generate a report and show all the names related to the id's.

Comment: @TheAlpha The table I've shown is placed in one table to generate all reports. However the 4 columns starting from crime_type_id is in different table.

Answer (score 1):

In your crime_reports table you need to add relationships to all 4 tables accordingly. Check more on a relationship here : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#introduction

Just for the time being I'm considering all are 1:1 relationship, then in your crime_reports model table you'll add relationship as follows :

```
class CrimeReports extends Model
{
    public function crime_type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne("App\CrimeType",'id','crime_type_id');
    }

    //add all other relations 
}
```

Now in your controller you can do :

```
public function index()
{   
   $display_crime = CrimeReport::with('crime_type', 'comma_seperated_other_relations')->get();
   return view('crimereports.index',compact('display_crime'));
}
```

**FOR SINGLE ATTRIBUTE**

If you just want a single attribute, then in your controller method, do

```
public function index()
{   
   $display_crime = CrimeReport::all();
   foreach($display_crime as $ds)
        $ds->crime_type_field = $ds->crime_type->name;
   return view('crimereports.index',compact('display_crime'));
}
```

It would be accessible in your by using attribute `crime_type_field` of a particular $ds

Comment: many thanks. I got the idea now. But what would be the structure of the query if I want to fetch other table and display it with the $display_crime variable?Can you give me just a sample.

Comment: You just have to add other relations (say suspect) and add the relation as an argument to the with method like so  $display_crime = CrimeReport::with('crime_type', 'suspect' )->get();

Comment: I figured it out yeah.Thanks again.

Comment: Im getting null values when i fetch data using foreach .When I use echo $ds->crime_name;

Comment: Does a relation for crime_name exist i.e. Have you added it? And are you passing it in with method?

Comment: I included my Model on top. Yeah i added those ralationships

Comment: According to your code, you should use $ds->crimeName.

Comment: But It will return all the attributes. I only want the crime_name how can I achieved that?

Comment: can anyone help me on this?

Comment: its not working with one to many relationship.. Any solution? Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94182/discussion-between-bharat-geleda-and-jay-gorio).